# Adding Custom dialogs in Visual Studio Setup projects

Tags: .net, setup-deployment

I need to develop a Visual Studio Setup Project for my application.
As far as i see, i can use only a handful of preconfigured dialogs which i can use.
Is there any way possible to use any custom dialogs in Visual Studio SetUp Project ?

For ex:

Whenever i start my setup, a dialog should be shown to the user prompting him to select a language for installation.

The user then shall select a language based on his preference and the installation shall then commence thereafter.

I hope i have made myself clear 
CL

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Setup projects.

Get down to WIX - downloa the Votive plugin (part of the WIX project) and then you can use WIX to generate the setup projects.

Multi langauge, btw., is not easy. Because MSI can not be multi language - so basically it runs into a transform for every language and a bootstrap application applying the transform.

If that is really your requirement, I suggest going with Installshield or Wise - they come with localization support built in.